# How to calculate equations in python? (eg. 2*2*2)

Tags: python

can anyone give me the code needed to calculate sums and equations in python?
E.g 2*2*2

I have tried things such as

Print "2*2*2"
and such

nothing gave me an answer

Comment: first of all, 2*2*2 is an expression, not equation

Comment: What Python version? Either `python --version` from cmd line or run a script containing: `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: Note `print "2*2*2"` returns `"2*2*2"` because `"..."` indicates a string of text and not an expression. In other-words it's doing exactly as you told it to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the python shell (type `python` in terminal or cmd), type

```
print(2*2*2)
```

to print the result.
You can also type

```
2*2*2
```

and it will print `8` again.
This should work. Write the same line in a script and it will work too. However, in a script, you can't just type 2*2*2 to print the results, you need to use `print()`.

If instead of writnig 2*2*2, you need to do something like 1+2+3+4+5, which is a sum on a list like `list=[1,2,3,4,5]`, simply write

```
sum(list)
```

If you want to do the sum of some elements in a dictionary like `d={1:2,2:4,3:8,4:16,5:32,6:64}` on the element from 3 to 5 inclusively, do

```
sum(d[i] for i in range(3, 5 + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Either don't pass it as string like:

Python 3

```
print(2*2*2)
```

Python 2

```
print 2*2*2
```

Or use eval function, like:

```
print(eval("2*2*2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your Python version, by running `python --version`.

In Python 2.x, `print` can be called without parentheses, but one of the main changes in Python 3.x is that `print(...)` requires them.

Python is a dynamic language, where types are inferred from their use. "2*2*2" is a *string type*, that depending on your version you can be printed by using either `print "2*2*2"`, or `print("2*2*2")`.

The returned data types can sometimes be confusing

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> 2*2*2      # This will return an integer
8
>>> 2.*2.*2.   # This will return a floating-point number
8.0
>>> "2*2*2"    # This will return the literal string
'2*2*2'
>>> 2*"hello"  # This will again, return a string
'hellohello'
```